# Which diashow viewer has a shuffle functionality?

Tags: photo-management, image-viewers

I would like to see all images in my image library in a diashow in a shuffled order. I tried some viewers, but they don't get along with my 100GB of photos or they want me to copy all folders in a library which is not desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The photo viewer `gwenview` has such an option although it cannot show images in subfolders:

- open fullscreen
- move the mouse to the top and click on the settings icon:

[image]

There you see a setting "Random" (or "Zufällig" here in german).

Although it is not perfect, it has one drawback:

- you cannot start a diashow with all containing picutes in several folders
  (only the pictures in the folder itself are taken for the diashow, not the images in subfolders)